# Are parent-child relationships possible in OpenCMIS?

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

I need to create a relationship between documents like **parent-child**. Does **OpenCMIS** provide a direct way? What is the actual use of 'relationship'?

Here is my sample code for **relationship**. How do I fetch these relational documents (I mean by providing parent document, list all child documents).

```
newFolderProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
newFolderProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
newFolderProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "ADGFolderAssociations");
Folder folderAssociations = target.createFolder(newFolderProps);

newFileProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID,
        "D:cmiscustom:document");
newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "ADGFileSource");
Document sourceDoc = folderAssociations.createDocument(
        newFileProps, null, VersioningState.MAJOR);

newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "ADGFileTarget");
Document targetDoc = folderAssociations.createDocument(
        newFileProps, null, VersioningState.MAJOR);

Map<String, String> relProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
relProps.put("cmis:sourceId", sourceDoc.getId());
relProps.put("cmis:targetId", targetDoc.getId());
relProps.put("cmis:objectTypeId", "R:cmiscustom:assoc");
ObjectId relId = session.createRelationship(relProps, null,
        null, null);
```

Is there any other way to achieve parent-child relationships in Alfresco using OpenCMIS?

Comment: Does the [Apache Chemistry example for listing a folder](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-list-folder.html) not cover you?

Comment: @Gagravarr: ya. Is that the only solution? Then what is the use of session.createRelationship() ?

Comment: Many repositories (including Alfresco) support additional kinds of relationships, beyond the primary parent/child filing, I believe it's mostly aimed at those